# What is meant by "Get the kettle going. it's thirsty work, this."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And it is only early afternoon - if we can make enough smoke, make enough noise till the sun goes down, they'll settle somewhere else perhaps....

And then:

> **Get the kettle going. it's thirsty work, this.**

(Reference: A Mild Attack of Locusts by Doris Lessing)

The context says that an effort is being made to stop locusts from landing on farmlands by making hue and cry and clamor with tin cans and other bits of metals. In this reference the sentence **Get the kettle going** is taught with the sense to keep the noise and clamor going on as it's a work that makes thirsty which appears irrational. So what is the actual sense of this sentences here?

Comment: Why do you think it's irrational that doing work banging pots together would make someone thirsty?

Comment: Presumably they are 'putting the kettle on' to make tea!

Answer (score 3):

"Put the kettle on" refers to preparing tea, presumably for the worker's to drink. In that context "it's thirsty work" means that the process of yelling, making noise, and particularly making smoke will make the worker's thirsty, so the tea will be wanted.

"Put the kettle on" is a fixed phrase if not an idiom, particularly in the UK, but also elsewhere, for making tea.

Comment: Yes, and it is probably the most used phrase in British TV shows that take places of residence. So get x going is the structure. One usually hears: put the kettle on. it's not its.